# Machine Learning - Features selection and Modeling (Connection between samples)

Tags: machine-learning, data-modeling

I am new to Machine Learning, and I have got several questions with my data now.

Let's say I have X samples, Y features and I also have the connection between x1 and x2 (e.g. the interaction count)

As most of the tutorial of Machine Learning start with labels specifically labelled at the sample itself...

I would like to ask how I should build the model? I want to have a model that it can predict two specific samples to see how high the interaction counts would be.

Giving me a direction/ keywords to learn would be good enough, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: Sorry but I think it is a valid question, I have got several suggestion on other group already, and I am posting it here as well (don't know if it is the right way of doing so)

Comment: No its not. You can post this on https://stats.stackexchange.com. Only programming related questions (which this is not, this is asking for the design and way for solution) are on-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

I have got others suggestion for the approach:

Formulate the problem as z=f(x1,x2), i.e. label depends on tuple of sample. if a dataset of ((x1,x2)=>z) is prepared, it can then be used to train regression, decision trees or networks.